# Nested document & Parent/Child setup using Spring Boot + Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

According to official elasticsearch, I'm understand that Nested required to reindexing the parent with all its children if add/delete/update operations, therefore is expensive when required a lot modification.

Example using Nested:

```
@Document(indexName = "test-index-person-multiple-level-nested", type = "user", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class PersonMultipleLevelNested {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<GirlFriend> girlFriends;

    //Getter, setter & constructor
}
```

And Parent & Child are better suite this kind situation, but how can I setup using Spring Data Elasticsearch? It is not yet supported? Seem can't find related documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about documentation, but there is a unit test for this feature: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/entities/ParentEntity.java — see `@Parent` in particular.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still can't get the idea from the unit test code. Why the child class is inside parent class. Not like conventional JPA style?
Eg: private List<GirlFriend> girlFriends; This is because I do want to support for both elasticsearch & hibernate...

Comment: Don't think you have to put them into the same class. Have you tried it out?